# I want to fork some memecoin in arbitrum goerli but I have some errors

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, ether, error

Alert
This contract may be abstract, it may not implement an abstract parent's methods completely or it may not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly.

Gas estimation failed
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"invalid opcode: PUSH0","id":5547835190118345}

this is the code

```
/**
 *Submitted for verification at Etherscan.io on 2023-07-02
 */

// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity 0.8.20;

abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }
}

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)
        external
        returns (bool);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender)
        external
        view
        returns (uint256);

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(
        address indexed owner,
        address indexed spender,
        uint256 value
    );
}

library SafeMath {
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");
        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
    }

    function sub(
        uint256 a,
        uint256 b,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a - b;
        return c;
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");
        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
    }

    function div(
        uint256 a,
        uint256 b,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }
}

contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;
    address private _previousOwner;
    event OwnershipTransferred(
        address indexed previousOwner,
        address indexed newOwner
    );

    constructor() {
        address msgSender = _msgSender();
        _owner = msgSender;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
    }

    function owner() public view returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(_owner == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }
}

interface IUniswapV2Factory {
    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB)
        external
        returns (address pair);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router02 {
    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external;

    function factory() external pure returns (address);

    function WETH() external pure returns (address);

    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint256 amountTokenDesired,
        uint256 amountTokenMin,
        uint256 amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    )
        external
        payable
        returns (
            uint256 amountToken,
            uint256 amountETH,
            uint256 liquidity
        );
}

contract FORK is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    mapping(address => uint256) private _rOwned;
    mapping(address => uint256) private _tOwned;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;
    mapping(address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;
    mapping(address => bool) private bots;
    mapping(address => uint256) private cooldown;
    uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);

    uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
    uint256 private _tFeeTotal;

    uint256 private _feeAddr1;
    uint256 private _feeAddr2;
    uint256 private _initialTax = 20;
    uint256 private _finalTax = 1;
    uint256 private _reduceTaxAt = 1;
    uint256 private _startLiquidateAt = 40;
    uint256 private _buyCount = 0;
    address payable private _feeAddrWallet;

    string private constant _name = unicode"forkcoin";
    string private constant _symbol = unicode"FORK";
    uint8 private constant _decimals = 9;

    IUniswapV2Router02 private uniswapV2Router;
    address private uniswapV2Pair;
    bool private tradingOpen;
    bool private inSwap = false;
    bool private swapEnabled = false;
    bool private cooldownEnabled = false;
    uint256 private constant _tTotal = 1000000000 * 10**_decimals;
    uint256 private _maxTxAmount = 20000000 * 10**_decimals;
    uint256 private _maxWalletSize = 20000000 * 10**_decimals;
    uint256 private _swapThreshold = 5000000 * 10**_decimals;
    event MaxTxAmountUpdated(uint256 _maxTxAmount);
    modifier lockTheSwap() {
        inSwap = true;
        _;
        inSwap = false;
    }

    constructor() {
        _feeAddrWallet = payable(_msgSender());
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[_feeAddrWallet] = true;

        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
    }

    function name() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public pure returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public pure override returns (uint256) {
        return _tTotal;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)
        public
        override
        returns (bool)
    {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender)
        public
        view
        override
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount)
        public
        override
        returns (bool)
    {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(
            sender,
            _msgSender(),
            _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(
                amount,
                "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"
            )
        );
        return true;
    }

    function setCooldownEnabled(bool onoff) external onlyOwner {
        cooldownEnabled = onoff;
    }

    function addBots(address[] memory bots_) public onlyOwner {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < bots_.length; i++) {
            bots[bots_[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    function delBots(address[] memory notbot) public onlyOwner {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < notbot.length; i++) {
            bots[notbot[i]] = false;
        }
    }

    function tokenFromReflection(uint256 rAmount)
        private
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        require(
            rAmount <= _rTotal,
            "Amount must be less than total reflections"
        );
        uint256 currentRate = _getRate();
        return rAmount.div(currentRate);
    }

    function _approve(
        address owner,
        address spender,
        uint256 amount
    ) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");
        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) private {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");

        if (from != owner() && to != owner()) {
            require(!bots[from] && !bots[to]);
            _feeAddr1 = 1;
            _feeAddr2 = (_buyCount >= _reduceTaxAt) ? _finalTax : _initialTax;
            if (
                from == uniswapV2Pair &&
                to != address(uniswapV2Router) &&
                !_isExcludedFromFee[to] &&
                cooldownEnabled
            ) {
                // Cooldown
                require(amount <= _maxTxAmount, "Exceeds the _maxTxAmount.");
                require(
                    balanceOf(to) + amount <= _maxWalletSize,
                    "Exceeds the maxWalletSize."
                );
                _buyCount++;
            }

            uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
            if (
                !inSwap &&
                to == uniswapV2Pair &&
                swapEnabled &&
                contractTokenBalance >= _swapThreshold &&
                _buyCount > _startLiquidateAt
            ) {
                swapTokensForEth(
                    _swapThreshold > amount ? amount : _swapThreshold
                );
                uint256 contractETHBalance = address(this).balance;
                if (contractETHBalance > 0) {
                    sendETHToFee(address(this).balance);
                }
            }
        } else {
            _feeAddr1 = 0;
            _feeAddr2 = 0;
        }

        _tokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private lockTheSwap {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    function removeLimits() external onlyOwner {
        _maxTxAmount = _tTotal;
        _maxWalletSize = _tTotal;
    }

    function sendETHToFee(uint256 amount) private {
        _feeAddrWallet.transfer(amount);
    }

    function openTrading() external onlyOwner {
        require(!tradingOpen, "trading is already open");
        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(
            0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D
        );
        uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), _tTotal);
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());
        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: address(this).balance}(
            address(this),
            balanceOf(address(this)),
            0,
            0,
            owner(),
            block.timestamp
        );
        swapEnabled = true;
        cooldownEnabled = true;

        tradingOpen = true;
        IERC20(uniswapV2Pair).approve(
            address(uniswapV2Router),
            type(uint256).max
        );
    }

    function _tokenTransfer(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) private {
        _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    function _transferStandard(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 tAmount
    ) private {
        (
            uint256 rAmount,
            uint256 rTransferAmount,
            uint256 rFee,
            uint256 tTransferAmount,
            uint256 tFee,
            uint256 tTeam
        ) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
        _takeTeam(tTeam);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _takeTeam(uint256 tTeam) private {
        uint256 currentRate = _getRate();
        uint256 rTeam = tTeam.mul(currentRate);
        _rOwned[address(this)] = _rOwned[address(this)].add(rTeam);
    }

    function _reflectFee(uint256 rFee, uint256 tFee) private {
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rFee);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tFee);
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    function manualSwap() external {
        require(_msgSender() == _feeAddrWallet);
        uint256 tokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        if (tokenBalance > 0) {
            swapTokensForEth(tokenBalance);
        }
        uint256 ethBalance = address(this).balance;
        if (ethBalance > 0) {
            sendETHToFee(ethBalance);
        }
    }

    function isBot(address a) public view returns (bool) {
        return bots[a];
    }

    function _getValues(uint256 tAmount)
        private
        view
        returns (
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256
        )
    {
        (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tTeam) = _getTValues(
            tAmount,
            _feeAddr1,
            _feeAddr2
        );
        uint256 currentRate = _getRate();
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(
            tAmount,
            tFee,
            tTeam,
            currentRate
        );
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tTeam);
    }

    function _getTValues(
        uint256 tAmount,
        uint256 taxFee,
        uint256 TeamFee
    )
        private
        pure
        returns (
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256
        )
    {
        uint256 tFee = tAmount.mul(taxFee).div(100);
        uint256 tTeam = tAmount.mul(TeamFee).div(100);
        uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tTeam);
        return (tTransferAmount, tFee, tTeam);
    }

    function _getRValues(
        uint256 tAmount,
        uint256 tFee,
        uint256 tTeam,
        uint256 currentRate
    )
        private
        pure
        returns (
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256
        )
    {
        uint256 rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rFee = tFee.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rTeam = tTeam.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rTransferAmount = rAmount.sub(rFee).sub(rTeam);
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee);
    }

    function _getRate() private view returns (uint256) {
        (uint256 rSupply, uint256 tSupply) = _getCurrentSupply();
        return rSupply.div(tSupply);
    }

    function _getCurrentSupply() private view returns (uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rSupply = _rTotal;
        uint256 tSupply = _tTotal;
        if (rSupply < _rTotal.div(_tTotal)) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
        return (rSupply, tSupply);
    }
}
```